# Запись текста в QFile

Tags: c++, qt, файлы

Какой из способов записи текста в QFile является предпочтительным?

С использованием метода write

```
   QFile file("test.txt");
   if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
       file.write("My Text\n");
   }
  file.close();
```

или с использованием потока QTextStream

```
  QFile file("test.txt")
  if(file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly | QIODevice::Text)) {
       QTextStream out(&file);
       out << "My Text\n";
  }
  file.close()
```

Есть ли отличия в быстродействии при записи больших объемов текста?

Comment: Запись через QTextStream является более гибкой. Судя по справке её предпочтительнее использовать для записи текста. Но write может оказатся быстрее, т.к. не учавствует промежуточный класс.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задал как-то данный вопрос на английском Stack Overflow, опубликую здесь перевод [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53057593/10562449), может кому-нибудь пригодится.

`QIODevice::write` -- низкоуровневый байтовый интерфейс для записи необработанных данных на устройство. `QTextStream` -- высокоуровневый интерфейс для записи форматированного текста. Вероятно `QTextStream` реализован

Основной вариант использования `QTextStream` -- запись строк класса `QString`. Текстовый поток конвертирует строку из UTF-16 в локальную кодировку, установленную по умолчанию (обычно 8-битную), или в любую другую кодировку, установленную через `QTextStream::setCodec`.

QTextStream почти наверняка работает медленнее, т.к. выполняет больше операций, однако в большинстве случаев разница в скорости с `QIODevice::write` будет незначительна. Если необходимо собрать большую строку из сырых данных вручную, то вероятно лучше использовать `QIODevice::write`. Если необходимо записать форматированный текст, в том числе `QString`, то вероятно более предпочтительным будет использование `QTextStream`.